# Kendo Angular Grid Gives 'Unresolved Local Varibale'

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo UI for Angular Grid and I'm getting a warning from TypeScript that says 'Unresolved variable Name' and 'Unresolved variable Id' on this HTML:

```
<kendo-grid [selectable]="selectable360"
            [resizable]="true"
            [kendoGridSelectBy]="SelectedCallback"
            [selectedKeys]="Selected360"
            (cellClick)="SetGridDraggable()"
            *ngIf="ShowModelAsList && CurrentFolder"
            [kendoGridBinding]="CurrentFolder.Models">
  <kendo-grid-column title="Name" field="Name">
    <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
      <div>{{dataItem.Name}}</div>
      <div class="idIndicator">{{dataItem.Id}}</div>
    </ng-template>
  </kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Last Update" field="LastUpdate" width="150" format="g"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Update By" field="UpdateBy"></kendo-grid-column>
  <kendo-grid-column title="Version" field="Version" width="70" [style]="{'text-align': 'center'}"></kendo-grid-column>
</kendo-grid>
```

The data that it's bound as is just `Models: FileUI[];` and FileUI definitely has those properties:

```
export class FileUI implements BIM360ItemBase {
  // Interface Implementation
  public IsFolder = false;

  @JsonProperty('id', String)
  Id: string = undefined;

  @JsonProperty('parentId', String, true)
  ParentId: string | null = undefined;

  @JsonProperty('projectId', String)
  ProjectId: string = undefined;

  @JsonProperty('name', String)
  Name: string = undefined;

  // Class Properties
  @JsonProperty('thumbnail', String, true)
  ImagePath: string | null = undefined;
  Version: string;
  LastUpdate: Date;
  UpdateBy: string;

  @JsonProperty('directoryId', String)
  DirectoryId: string = undefined;

  @JsonProperty('fileType', FileType)
  FileType: FileType = undefined;
}
```

I'm getting similar warnings in many other ng-template tags as well but this is a good concise example.  I know that it's all working because I can build it and it displays correctly, but I'd like to get rid of the warnings if possible.

Why is it telling me it's not defined and how can I fix it?